# How to limit output of ls to only show filename, date and size?

Tags: linux, unix

How can I use `ls` in linux to get a listing of filenames date and size only? I don't need to see the other info such as owner, permission.

Comment: which Linux are we talking about?

Comment: apache server..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ls -l | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $9}'`

This will print the file size in bytes, month, date, and filename.

```
jin@encrypt /tmp/foo % ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 jin  wheel  68 Oct  4 12:43 bar
drwxr-xr-x  2 jin  wheel  68 Oct  4 12:43 baz
drwxr-xr-x  2 jin  wheel  68 Oct  4 12:43 quux

jin@encrypt /tmp/foo % ls -l | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $9}'
68 Oct 4 bar
68 Oct 4 baz
68 Oct 4 quux
```

Comment: @Sosukudo Yeah, I'm not sure either. But people seem to agree that it's ok to downvote bad questions but not the answers if they're useful. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98197/should-users-be-penalized-for-answering-bad-questions

Comment: @Sosukodo: feel free to upvote now :)

Comment: no support for filenames with multiple spaces

Answer (score 17):

Technically, it's not possible with `ls`, but `find` can do the same job with its `-printf` switch:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -printf '%t %s %p\n'
```

Comment: You're suggestion is my winner, and I'd recommend that if people are interested in more fields for the printf they RTFM. For example, show me the permissions for all files which are not a directory :

`find usr/lib/ -not -type d -printf '%M %p\n`

output:

`-rw-r--r-- usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/apr-util-1/apr_crypto_openssl-1.so`
...

Teach a man to fish and all that...

Comment: Question is regarding linux so not unreasonable answer, but for the record this requires GNU find.

Answer (score 5):

you can always do:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  6 23:29 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  6 23:29 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  6 23:30 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  6 23:30 file4
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  6 23:30 file5
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  6 23:30 file6
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  0 Oct  6 23:30 file7
```

`cut` it to:

```
$ ls -l | cut -f 8-13 -d ' '

0 Oct  6 23:29 file1
0 Oct  6 23:29 file2
0 Oct  6 23:30 file3
0 Oct  6 23:30 file4
0 Oct  6 23:30 file5
0 Oct  6 23:30 file6
0 Oct  6 23:30 file7

$
```

Comment: doesnt work with: variable ownerships, groups, file sizes

Comment: Cut does not collapse consecutive delimiters, where as `ls -l` uses whitespace padding. If your columns are not uniform length (which column 5, file size will often not), cut will not select columns correctly. Collapsing consecutive spaces will help (watch out for spaces in file names). `ls -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 8-13 -d ' '`

Answer (score 5):

Another non-`ls` way:

```
> stat --printf='%y\t%12s\t%-16n|\n' tmp.*
2017-06-15 10:42:07.252853000 +0200         10485760    tmp.1           |
2017-06-15 10:41:25.659570000 +0200              666    tmp.TKPzm3BfRw  |
```

Explanation: `%y` = human-readable modification date; 
`%s` = size in bytes (`%12s` right-aligned, length 12);
`%n` = file name (`%-16n` left-aligned, length 16); `\t` = tab, `\n` = linefeed. `|` = literal pipe char, just to show the end of the file name.

Like `ls`, `stat` has no options to select which files to show. (That can be done by shell globbing as shown above or some `find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 stat ...`, for example.)

Comment: Question was about linux, so your answer is fine, but for anyone who cares, here's an equivalent for FreeBSD stat.  `stat -f '%N %Sm %z' filename`

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation on tolitius

```
ls -lh | cut -f 6- -d ' '
```

Comment: Care to explain what the variation adds?

Comment: Just removes the need to specify the number of the end field by using the 6- in stead of 6-x